# while using detectron CUDAERROR: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: pytorch

I'm running detectron2 on jupyter in docker container

```
trainer.train()
```

then I got

```
[06/03 01:17:49 d2.engine.train_loop]: Starting training from iteration 0
ERROR [06/03 01:17:49 d2.engine.train_loop]: Exception during training:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 132, in train
    self.run_step()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 215, in run_step
    loss_dict = self.model(data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py", line 121, in forward
    features = self.backbone(images.tensor)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/fpn.py", line 123, in forward
    bottom_up_features = self.bottom_up(x)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/resnet.py", line 459, in forward
    x = self.stem(x)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/resnet.py", line 392, in forward
    x = F.relu_(x)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
[06/03 01:17:49 d2.engine.hooks]: Total training time: 0:00:00 (0:00:00 on hooks)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3435b262f1ae> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py in train(self)
    399             OrderedDict of results, if evaluation is enabled. Otherwise None.
    400         """
--> 401         super().train(self.start_iter, self.max_iter)
    402         if len(self.cfg.TEST.EXPECTED_RESULTS) and comm.is_main_process():
    403             assert hasattr(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py in train(self, start_iter, max_iter)
    130                 for self.iter in range(start_iter, max_iter):
    131                     self.before_step()
--> 132                     self.run_step()
    133                     self.after_step()
    134             except Exception:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py in run_step(self)
    213         If you want to do something with the losses, you can wrap the model.
    214         """
--> 215         loss_dict = self.model(data)
    216         losses = sum(loss_dict.values())
    217         self._detect_anomaly(losses, loss_dict)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/rcnn.py in forward(self, batched_inputs)
    119             gt_instances = None
    120 
--> 121         features = self.backbone(images.tensor)
    122 
    123         if self.proposal_generator:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/fpn.py in forward(self, x)
    121         """
    122         # Reverse feature maps into top-down order (from low to high resolution)
--> 123         bottom_up_features = self.bottom_up(x)
    124         x = [bottom_up_features[f] for f in self.in_features[::-1]]
    125         results = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    457     def forward(self, x):
    458         outputs = {}
--> 459         x = self.stem(x)
    460         if "stem" in self._out_features:
    461             outputs["stem"] = x

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/modeling/backbone/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    390     def forward(self, x):
    391         x = self.conv1(x)
--> 392         x = F.relu_(x)
    393         x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
    394         return x

RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

this is my environment:

```
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.5.0+cu101
Is debug build: No
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.1

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
GCC version: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
CMake version: Could not collect

Python version: 3.7
Is CUDA available: Yes
CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce RTX 3070
Nvidia driver version: 460.73.01
cuDNN version: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7.6.5

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip] numpy==1.18.1
[pip] torch==1.5.0+cu101
[pip] torchvision==0.6.0+cu101
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl  
[conda] mkl                       2020.1                      217  
[conda] mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py37h23d657b_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h0573a6f_0  
[conda] torch                     1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.6.0+cu101              pypi_0    pypi
```

I checked it by

```
! python -m torch.utils.collect_env
```

Comment: your pytorch build doesn't support your RTX 3070 GPU.  see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31285).  Yes, there is a lot to read there.

Comment: After I install pytorch 1.7.0 with cuda 11.0 I solved problem! Thanks